# Theme in android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

How can I combine

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"`

and

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

on android-manifest.xml or in values/style.xml?

Comment: What do you mean by "mix"?

Comment: I mean I'd like to combine the two themes. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: There's already a full screen material light theme, no?

Comment: Removed xml tag because it is too broad, added more precise tags. Slightly improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the relevant attributes from the second and add them to the first. You can do this by extending the first theme in styles.xml.

An example of adding NoActionBar to a theme is below:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Taken from here:

https://github.com/Austin-Android/austin-feeds-me/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Woot! Please except the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend only a single parent in  tag. You have cherry the style properties needed in second and apply something like below.

```
 <style name="Themelight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
 </style>
```

Refer android developer document related to style inheritance https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html#Inheritance